# How do I download the code for a specific google cloud "service"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

[This doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/downloading-source-code) show the command to download the source of an app I have in app engine:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_APP_ID] -V [YOUR_APP_VERSION] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

That's fine, but I also have services that I deployed. Using this command I can only seem to download the "default" service. I also deployed "myservice01" and "myservice02" to app engine in my GCP project. How do I specify the code of a specific service to download?

I tried this command as suggested:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_APP_ID] -M [YOUR_MODULE] -V [YOUR_APP_VERSION] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

It didn't fail but this is the output I got (and it didn't download anything)

```
01:30 AM Host: appengine.google.com
01:30 AM Fetching file list...
01:30 AM Fetching files...
```

Now as a test I tried it with the name of a module I know doesn't exist and I got this error:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Version ... of Module ... does not exist.
```

So I at least know it's successfully finding the module and version, but doesn't seem to want to download them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also specify the module (*services* used to be called *modules*):

> -M MODULE, --module=MODULE
>
> Set the module, overriding the module value from
>     app.yaml.

So something like:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_APP_ID] -M [YOUR_MODULE] -V [YOUR_APP_VERSION] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

Side note: `YOUR_APP_VERSION` should really read `YOUR_MODULE_VERSION` :)

Of course, the answer assumes the app code downloads were **not** permanently disabled from the Console's [GAE App Settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings) page:

> **Permanently prohibit code downloads**
>
> Once this is set, no one, including yourself, will ever be able to
>   download the code for this application using the appcfg download_app
>   command.

Comment: I don't deny this is the right command but its not working for me, see edit to my post.

Comment: Hmm that setting isnt' enabled and I _was_ able to download the default service

Comment: Last thought I have: is code actually deployed in that service version? I once deployed an empty repo (well, just an almost empty app.yaml) to "delete" the deployed code. Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: Yes, that was it, just check and the size of the version is 0 bytes.