# NodeJs - How to deploy a newer version of my app on Google cloud platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google cloud platform, Recently I deployed a Nodejs-MongoDB application on Google cloud platform. I followed [this article](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine) for that until this time everything worked perfectly fine.

Now I am trying to update the code using same steps, but changes are not reflecting. Before posting this question I checked for a solution over different forums and SO., but I couldn't find anything.

Also, how can I download my source code to verify the deployed version's source code? I tried to find **appcfg.py**  file but it does not exist on my machine.
If I have asked something invalid, I apologize in advance.
Thanks.

Comment: What are those "same steps" exactly? Logs for them? What changes are you doing to the app?

Comment: For downloading the code see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181876/downloading-app-engine-source-code

Comment: You can go to console -> Stackdriver -> Debug to see you actual code.

Comment: Can you run the app locally? Are the changes reflected there? If so, did you deploy it to AppEngine? You can deploy with `gcloud app deploy`. You need to install the SDK if you want to use appcfg.py, available here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for replying, I want to modify a block of code. It works on the local machine. And I am using `gcloud app deploy`  to deploy my app.

Comment: @blueCat I checked it many times,  but nothing to show there. I used `npm install --save @google-cloud/debug-agent` and `require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start();` to debug the app, but still no luck. Thanks!

Comment: @user835611 Thank you for replying, 1) can you run the app locally => Yes I can. 2) Are the changes reflected there= > Yes they are.
3) If so, did you deploy it to AppEngine => yes, am using `gcloud app deploy` to deploy my app
I have downloaded the Cloud SDK from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), Do I have to download SDK for AppEngine?

Comment: NodeJs doesn't have a GAE-specific SDK, both links eventually lead to the same Cloud SDK download page, so no worries from this perspective.

Comment: Are you deploying to the right project? You can stop the old running app in the Cloud Console (https://console.cloud.google.com/). There is also Stackdriver Logs that might give you some idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: @user835611 I have only one project in my account. Also, I don't see anything suspicious.

Comment: Can you re-deploy with something that offers an additional endpoint (I like to add a /hello route), so you see that the new app is actually running? Did you try with different browsers/incognito window to avoid caching problems?

Comment: @Shanky Has the troubleshooting solution worked for you?