# How to download Node.js project deployed on Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed the Node.js code on Google Cloud using following command:-

> gcloud app deploy

So, How to download Node.js project deployed on Google Cloud.

Comment: You have already deployed the app _and_ for  `gcloud app deploy` to work means you already have the source code.

Comment: I see you tagged your post with google-cloud-functions - which is a different product, deployed with a different command. Assuming you're indeed talking about a GAE flexible environment project (deployed with that command) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181876/downloading-app-engine-source-code/49277370#49277370

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you need Tomcat server then set and deploy node.js application inside by creating a folder and add the dist folder files in it.

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

Comment: i think question is regarding download

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time it is only possible to download your app's source code for Java, Python, PHP and Golang. The [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code) are similar for Python, Golang and PHP:

```
appcfg.py -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

where:

- `[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]` is your GCP project ID.
- `[YOUR_VERSION_ID]` is the version ID of your application that you want to download.
- `[OUTPUT_DIR]` is the full directory path to where you want your files downloaded.

In Java you use `appcfg.sh`:

```
appcfg.sh -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID] -V [YOUR_VERSION_ID] download_app [OUTPUT_DIR]
```

See the link above and also the reference for [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/appcfg-arguments) and [Python, PHP, Golang](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/appcfg-arguments)