# How to view deployed source file in GCP Console(AppEngine Flexible Environment)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm pretty new to the Google Cloud Platform. I have deployed a Python 3 Flask app in AppEngine Flexible Environment using the Google Cloud SDK and the app works fine. I just want to view the source files deployed, in the cloud. Is there any way to view my project files in GCP?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181876/downloading-app-engine-source-code

Comment: @DanCornilescu I have the source code, but I just want to view the files in cloud using the GCP console/terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: Not directly, as the cloud console doesn't run on the same instance, but you can connect to the instance: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance

Answer (score 19):

You can view the source files by clicking on **tools > debug** next to the app version on your [versions page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions)

Alternative, you can go to your [instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances), click on SSH next to one of the instances and you will enter the debug mode for that specific instance.

This will open a console in your browser and you can start a shell in the container that is running your app, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance).

PS: apparently this is possible only for the Flexible Environment

Comment: I use appengine standard and I can acces the compiled files in versions > tools > debug

Comment: So in other words, there are certain files which cannot be accessed via the GCP GUI but can only be accessed/viewed through the cloud shell, and the steps you've outlined do that, right?

Comment: none of this is working for me. the `deployed files` list is empty showing `source not available` and the debugger says it could not find a target for `default - prod` and to make sure it's up and serving requests (it is)