# Downloading Legacy PHP code from Google Cloud Project given appcfg is deprecated?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Google search suggests 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code

However this is deprecated

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I download my code from GCP as the tool is deprecated?

Comment: The post from Google mentioned 'deprecated'. I don't know how to answer your question. Is there a forum on there for it possibly?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, this function is deprecated. However, there are some tricks that you can use in order to obtain the code of your application as it's uploaded to a bucket when you deploy.

I suggest you take a look as [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181876/downloading-app-engine-source-code) as this is explained into a bit more detail.

Hope you find this useful.